# when use zim frame for zsh，read-only variable: _zim_fpath error

Tags: zsh, zshrc

env：

- zsh 5.8.1 (arm-apple-darwin21.3.0)
- zimfw

when `source ~/.zshrc`，occur

```
/Users/username/.zim/init.zsh:3: read-only variable: _zim_fpath
```

I have not find any question for it!

I tried to annotation this code，but will refresh and recover this line.

Comment: At least show the line which produces the error. Most likely, the variable `_zim_fpath` is read-only, but the code is trying to reassign it.

Comment: You should ask this on the Zimfw repo, not here. SO is not a customer support forum.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But it is fixed after I updated zimfw.

```
zimfw upgrade
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).